# Get SQL server instance installation date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know the date when the sql server installed on the system. 
I did try to look in %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\ directory but there are so many files and folder not sure from where I can get the required information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sys.server_principals view to get the date:

```
SELECT  create_date
FROM    sys.server_principals
WHERE   name = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM';
```

Check out [server_principals on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786(v=sql.105).aspx).